# RefineryCMS - Page Templates of Page-Parts possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

Im looking at Rails based CMS's, Refinery looks very nice, clean and simple however I cant find any clarification if templating is possible, or is to be included.

Ive found this [pull request](https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms/pull/677). Is this feature now available?

Ive also been looking at Locomotive but the documentation is very sparse at best.

Thanks.

Edit - Sorry, there was not enough of an explanation of what I meant by a template. Is it possible to define the page-parts that a certain page has. Eg I add a "City" page type, which has 5 page-parts, Name, Postcode, Description, Longitude and Latitude. So when a user adds a page, they then choose a page type, in this case a City and that has the pre-defined page-parts in it.

I have seen the copywriting but it does not appear possible to pre-define things when adding a new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add up `layout.css` in your stylesheets directory and it will automatically get picked up.

check out this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/332-refinery-cms-basics) episode for more information.

Edit:

You could use the `rails g refinery:engine city name:string ....`

It will generate a whole bunch of stuff, follow the instructions printed by this command and you could see a new admin page to CRUD cities and a new app with views to set the HTML of show/index pages.

Comment: Sorry, i didnt add enough of an explanation of what I meant by a template. Edited original question.

Comment: By creating a new engine you will basically create a small rails app that has views that you could edit for one specific type of entries in your case cities. If you have a new type of entries, lets say "countries" then you have to create new engine for it with different views

Comment: Ahh, I see - Ive also just found http://refinerycms.com/guides/getting-started-with-refinery which I should have read first! Thanks :)

Comment: Well It doesnt seem good idea for creating new engine for every thing, i mean if I have to create controllers, views for every single page, why would I use a cms, I can write my own code.


Lets say I have a abouts us page, with two page parts and a team page four page parts and I will style both of them differently, If I modify show.html.erb, it is going to affect both aboutus and team pages, How can I create separate view for both of this pages, some thing like show.html.erb for each one of them, is it possible ?